# Zebra ZXP series 8 Delphi API

Tags: delphi, zebra-printers

Have anyone worked with Zebra ZXP printers ?

I need to access the printer from Delphi, Feed one card to Contact reader, do some stuff with the smart card, then access the contactless chip, again do some stuff and, if everything is OK then do some printing, if there was an error with smart card the eject it without printing anything.

Some delphi wrapper for ZmotifPrinter.dll would be very nice :)

Comment: Something like [this?](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA232&actp=LIST_POPULAR)

Answer (score 0):

The ZMotif SDK can be used in Delphi: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/developer-tools/zmotif-sdk-zxp-series-8.html.  Their SDK doesn't provide direct smart-card encoding functionality; rather, it allows you to position the card to the reader at which point the smart card encoder (which is PC/SC compliant) can be controlled from any other applicable library as if it were a standalone reader.  Here is an example integrating their SDK with WinSCard.dll: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1371214373330&answerid=16777228&iqaction=5&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fkb%2Findex%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DSA280%26actp%3Dsearch%26viewlocale%3Den_US&highlightinfo=4194565,308,322#.  Otherwise, their SDK does let you control printing functionality.

While this may be a poor answer for the StackOverflow format, you can definitely contact zebra's technical support for sample applications.  They will almost certainly have sample applications for you in Delphi.  You can reach them at card_sdk_questions@zebra.com.